# Comments and Threads in Trello

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-boards

I am pretty new to Trello and am wondering whether it is possible to improve the looks of the comments under a card. Out of the box, they all run in one thread, which makes it difficult to read, especially once the number of comments grows. It would be neat if one could have threads by replying to specific comments. I have looked through the Improvements (add-ons) section inside Trello, but have not found anything.

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

As Juliane mentioned there is no way to do this with Trello's native comments section however we've just released a new Power-Up (app) for Trello that will allow you to thread comments in Trello.

https://trello.com/power-ups/61782018054e2f19837ace09

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way to thread comments in Trello.